# max/min-height/width does not have any effect on bootstrap container

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make a panel with fixed size. 
what am I doing wrong?

```
<div class="panel panel-info">
            <div class="panel-heading" style="max-height: 5%">
                <h1 style="text-align: center">bbbbbb</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
            </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add your max-width to your panel it should work, you can see below with the max-width of 50%. If you want it to be fixed in pixels just using a max-height: 100px would work. Also, you could try using the vh for height if you want it to be relative to the size of the screen. You could add this to either the panel, panel-heading, or panel-body to get the height you wanted. 1vh unit reflects 1/100th the height of the viewport. More info on vh/vw can be found here: http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/vm-vh-units

If you choose to use vh you should add a min-height vh that so that it would not get too small on lower resolutions.

```
<div class="panel panel-info" style="max-width: 50%;">
    <div class="panel-heading" style="max-height: 1vh">
        <h1 style="text-align: center">bbbbbb</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for the quike replay, but why my code does not work?

Comment: You could change your "max-height: 5%" to either "max-height: 5vh" or a pixel value of "max-height: 100px". Working with the % value doesn't seem to work well with bootstrap heights.